# Failed to connect to host Input Server Uri = https://pilot-payflowpro.paypal.com:443

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, payflowpro

I spent the last day and a half researching this problem to no avail. I found many similar problems, but none that exactly address my issue. I am attempting to integrate Payflow Pro with transparent redirect, but cannot successfully complete a transaction. I am using the test environment with a test Payflow Gateway account.

I can successfully retrieve a secure token by posting the following from my test server to https://pilot-payflowpro.paypal.com:

> PARTNER=[hidden]&VENDOR=[hidden]&USER=[hidden]&PWD=[hidden]&TRXTYPE=S&TENDER=C&CREATESECURETOKEN=Y&SECURETOKENID=20180916085333999&URLMETHOD=POST&SILENTTRAN=TRUE&AMT=2&BILLTOFIRSTNAME=John&BILLTOLASTNAME=Doe&BILLTOADDRESS=123TestDr.&BILLTOCITY=Testcity&BILLTOSTATE=TN&BILLTOZIP=55511&BILLTOEMAIL=johndoe@test.com&USER1=3&USER2=&USER3=0&USER4=2

to which I receive the following response:

> RESULT=0&SECURETOKEN=[hidden]&SECURETOKENID=20180916085333999&RESPMSG=Approved

NOTE: I have configured a Return URL using PayPal Manager, which is why RETURNURL is not included in the secure token request. However, I also have tried with RETURNURL specified, and I have obtained the same end result.

I use the results from the secure token request to create a cc collection form. I input test credit card details using acct# `5105105105105100`, then post the following from the browser directly to https://pilot-payflowlink.paypal.com:

> fund_id=3&ACCT=5105105105105100&CVV2=555&EXPMONTH=01&EXPYEAR=20&EXPDATE=0120&SECURETOKENID=20180916085333581&SECURETOKEN=[hidden]&feeTokenID=20180916085333999&feeToken=[hidden]

The response is properly redirected to the Hosted Page error URL I have specified in my Payflow Manager Service Settings. My problem is that I do not understand why it is redirecting to the error url  with the following message:

> RESPMSG=Failed to connect to host Input Server Uri = https://pilot-payflowpro.paypal.com:443

NOTE: The value above is only one part of the response sent to the error page. The rest of the return values include information from my original secure token request, which I would assume could only be returned if a successful connection had been established with the link in the error message??

To clearly state the problem:

1. I have already successfully connected from my test server to the link specified in the error message, when first I obtained the secure token.
2. The post that results in the error message was sent from the browser (in this case, on the same physical box as my test server) to https://pilot-payflowlink.paypal.com, which is not the URL specified in the error message.
3. Finally, the error seemingly occurs during the Payflow process - to my understanding, there should not be a call from my server or the browser to the link in the error message at this point during the process. I mention this specifically to address the many search results I found relating this particular error message to PayPal's requirement for TLS1.2, which is already properly configured on my server (I should mention for the sake of completeness, I do still have TLS1.0 enabled on my test server, but cannot disable it for unrelated reasons. Nonetheless, I was able to successfully connect to obtain a secure token, and my server passes PayPal's own TLS test at https://tlstest.paypal.com/).

I should mention that I also have tried to complete this same transaction on our production server, still using test credentials and test endpoints at PayPal, with exactly the same results. The test server is also set up for TLS1.2 with TLS1.0 enabled, and also passes PayPal's test.

This problem may be the one that pushes me full-on into insanity, so any help really would be appreciated!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who might find this question and be similarly frustrated, I want to share that I was able to solve the problem by creating a new Payflow Gateway test account.

I spent a great deal of time on trial and error solutions with no success, and PayPal Merchant Technical Services was able to duplicate the problem but was also unable to find a solution. Finally, after simplifying my test app as much as possible (two bare-bones HTML forms filled in and submitted manually), I came to the conclusion that there might be something wrong with my test account. Upon creating a new account with new credentials, then inserting them back into my original code, everything worked perfectly.

As of this morning, PayPal MTS is continuing to research the problem, since others have reported similar issues.

For others with similar problems, it is worth noting that I am now able to complete transactions while TLS 1.0 remains enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Disabling TLS1.0 has helped others with this issue. If you keep having problems, contact PayPal's support

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I tried that and received the same results. I am, however, able to connect to pilot-payflowpro to get a secure token, even with TLS1.0 enabled. It is only when I connect to pilot-payflowLINK that I receive an error message about failure to connect to pilot-payflowPRO. I am in touch with PayPal MTS, but they have been unable to resolve the problem thus far, hence my post here.